# Extension methods on base generic interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm implementing a fluent builder pattern that requires accepting enumerables in a static extension method and iterating through its contents, while applying a functor to the enumerable's contents. As in (not the actual code, just an illustration):

```
public static IValidator<IEnumerable<T>> Each<T>(
    this IValidator<IEnumerable<T>> enumerable, 
    Func<T, bool> action)
{
    foreach (T value in enumerable)
        action(value);

    return validator;
}
```

This works pretty well for enumerables but fails for inherited types/interfaces. Let's say:

```
IValidator<IEnumerable<Guid>> validator = ...;

IEnumerable<Guid> guids = ...;
validator.Each(guids, guid => guid != Guid.Empty);   // ok

IList<Guid> guids = ...;
validator.Each(guids, guid => guid != Guid.Empty);   // doesn't compile (see below)
```

The exception is:

> `IValidator<IList<Guid>>` does not contain a definition for 'Each' 
>   and no extension method 'Each' accepting a first argument of type 
>   `IValidator<IList<Guid>>` could be found (are you missing a using 
>   directive or an assembly reference?

My question is about the inheritance chain of `IValidator<T>` and, more specifically, its generic type arguments `T`. Why is type `IValidator<IEnumerable<T>>` not assignable from `IValidator<IList<T>>`? There's no circumstance I can think of on which `IList<T>` is not an `IEnumerable<T>` (given the same `T`).

Constraining the generic argument to `T : IEnumerable<R>` does work but that requires two type arguments (`T` and `R`) which I'd like to avoid, if possible.

Any thoughts? Better solutions? Thanks.

Comment: I think this could be a covariance and contravariance issue. Let me see if I can get some sample code to see if this the case.

Comment: Even if you solve your current problem, what's the point of the method?  You aren't using the boolean result of the functor passed in, so unless the functor mutates the object the net result is nothing changes, and if it does mutate it then...well...it shouldn't, as Linq is designed for queries, not mutation, of sequences.

Comment: @Servy - that's just a sample to illustrate my intentions, not the actual code. I left it as `Func<T, bool>` because it requires less code than `Action<T>` to write the calling lambdas in the example that follows. I was being a little lazy. :-)

Comment: IEnumerable (with .Net 4+) is covariant but IList is not because the later takes both input and output parameters.

Comment: @JasonEvans - Yes, it does seem so. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, while `IList<T>` is not. Although I think the problem might be that `IValidator` itself is not covariant. Any thoughts on how to overcome that?

Comment: @lsoliveira It is still indicative of bad design an poor programming practices.  If you want to perform an action on every item in an `IEnumerable` use a foreach loop on it; that's the most appropriate method.  Using `Func` when you know that you'll ignore the return value will just confuse users of your code, so it's not worth any potential code condensation (although I don't see how it's any more condensed).

Comment: OK, I haven't got time to write some code. My suggestion is when you're using `IValidator<T>` try `IValidator<out T>` or `IValidator<in T>`, I forget which one. You could also just use `var guids = validator.Each.....` which could help, though it won't remove your design issue.

Comment: @Servy - Just to clarify: `Validator.For(guids).IsNotNull().IsNotEmpty().Each(guid != Guid.Empty)`. Is the goal and it's working fine (for `IEnumerable`). The `Func` tells the validation engine to stop and throw the validation exception. Anyway, the doubt still stands.

Comment: @JasonEvans - thanks. Making the interface covariant by marking it with `out T` was the key (which is safe as there's no mutation of the members of `IValidator<T>` that are of type `T`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the definition of your `IValidator<T>` interface.  I'm betting it's something along the lines of:

```
public interface IValidator<T>
```

What you really want is:

```
public interface IValidator<out T>
```

This will make your interface [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), meaning that you can assign an implementation of `IValidator<T2>` to `IValidator<T>`, assuming that `T2` derives from `T`.

In this case, [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) derives from [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), so you *should* be able to declare `T` as covariant.  However, this depends on the methods on `IValidator<T>` and how they are exposed.

Namely, if you have methods on `IValidator<T>` that take instances of `T` in as a parameter to any methods on the interface, then you won't be able to declare the interface as covariant.

If this is the case, then you should be able to get away with this definition of `Each`:

```
public static IValidator<T> Each<T, TValue>(
    this IValidator<T> enumerable, 
    Func<TValue, bool> action) where T : IEnumerable<TValue>
{
    foreach (TValue value in enumerable)
        action(value);

    return validator;
}
```

This will indicate that `T` should derive from `IEnumerable<TValue>`.

Comment: After @JasonEvans comment above I remembered I had completely forgotten about co/contravariance. You're right on the mark. Making the interface covariant solved the issue. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Two answers:

1. It is perfectly legal to say `where T: IEnumerable<T>` which may solve your problem and doesn't require a second generic type.
2. `IValidator<IEnumerable<T>>` is not assignable from `IValidator<IList<T>>` because your interface is not variant. As of v4, C# does support interface variance, but you have to ask for it explicitly in your interface definition. To do so, see the [`out Generic Modifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)

Covariance is what allows you to substitute a more-derived type for a generic parameter that expects a less-derived type when doing assignments, etc.

Note that it's up to you to make sure your interface really is variant-safe. This is why it wasn't possible before C# 4, because it's not *always* true that it works; some interfaces are safely covariant, some are safely contravariant (you can only substitute *less* derived types for the expected type). It all depends on what you're doing.